# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: Angular

Tags: angular7, angular-router

hice un login y lugo redirijo a otro ruoter y en este  aparece el header y el footer pero no muestra lo componentes que se cargan en el  
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cambia tus fotos por código. Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Gracias

Comment: en tu `FeatureRoutingModule` no hay ninguna ruta que tenga el `path: 'inside'`. Como ves en tu vs code te marca que no usas el `InsideComponent`. Puede ser por eso